# create a Type that matches the Object which has unfixed counts of random keyNames with different value format

Tags: typescript, random, types, key

I need a Type which statisfy  Object that
has a firstName proptery , value format is string,
has a lastName proptery , value format is string,
other random keyName ,value format is string[ ],

```
const personA = {
 firstName:"Bob" //alwways exist, 
 lastName:"Tom", //alwways exist
 hobbies:["cooking","singing","dancing"] //not always exist in an object instant
 ableToSpeak:["english","japaneses"]
//...other random keyName with value of string[]
}

const personB = {
 firstName:"Jim"
 lastName:"kATE",
 food:["cake","apple","rice"]
 //...other random keyName  with value of string[]
}
```

The following is not working,
`firstName` and `[keyName]` are conflict

```
type HumanType {
  [keyName: string]: string[],
  firstName:string
  lastName:string
}
```

**`Property 'firstName' of type 'string' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'string[]'.`**

Answer (score 1):

Not perfect, but works by introducing new property

```
type HumanType {
  details?:Record<string,string[]>
  firstName:string
  lastName:string
}
```